# JSON Structure for parsing JSON data

Tags: ios, swift, nsjsonserialization

I want to parse this JSON,at the top level incoming JSON is an array,how can access to information of dictionary in array?

```
    [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Leanne Graham",
        "username": "Bret",
        "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
        "address": {
          "street": "Kulas Light",
          "suite": "Apt. 556",
          "city": "Gwenborough",
          "zipcode": "92998-3874",
          "geo": {
            "lat": "-37.3159",
            "lng": "81.1496"
          }
        },
        "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
        "website": "hildegard.org",
        "company": {
          "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
          "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
          "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
        }
      }
]
```

that is my code but I don't know how detect dictionary data.

```
func profileFromJSONData(data : NSData) -> ProfileResult {

        do{
            let jsonObject : [[String:AnyObject]]
            = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as! [[String:AnyObject]]

            for profileJSON in jsonObject {
                if let profile = profileFromJsonObject(profileJSON) {
                    finalProfile.append(profile)
                }
            }
            return .Success(finalProfile)
        }
        catch let error {
            return .Failure(error)
        }

    }
```

it is my profileFromJsonObject method for parse JSON into profile instance

```
func profileFromJsonObject(json: [String:AnyObject]) -> UserProfile?{

        guard let
            id = json["id"] as? Int,
            name = json["name"] as? String,
            userName = json["username"] as? String,
            email = json["email"] as? String,
            address = json["address"] as? NSDictionary,
            phone = json["phone"] as? String,
            website = json["website"] as? String,
            company = json["company"] as? NSDictionary
            else {
                return nil
        }

    let obj = UserProfile(id: id, name: name, userName: userName, email: email, address: address, phone: phone, website: website, company: company)
        return obj
    }
```

Comment: I'm call profileFromJsonObject function not profileFromJSONData.

Comment: in profileFromJsonObject function I'm parse json array into a profile instance.

Comment: Show ‘profileFromJsonObject‘ method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your JSON by taking it in local file, and I am able to parse to the model object in following way.
You just put your remote JSON in my code, i hope it will work

```
func getTheLocalJSON()
{
    let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("test", ofType: "json");
    let data = NSData.init(contentsOfFile: filePath!);

    var json : NSArray!
    do{
        json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! NSArray;
    }catch{

    }

    print("json \(json)");

    let dictResponse = json.objectAtIndex(0) as! NSDictionary;

    let objUser = profileFromJsonObject(dictResponse)! as UserProfile;

    print("user : \(objUser)");

    //Code to access company name and show it as screen title
    self.title = (objUser.company)!["name"] as? String;

    lblCompanyname.text = (objUser.company)!["name"] as? String;
    lblCatchPhrase.text = (objUser.company)!["catchPhrase"] as? String;
    lblbs.text = (objUser.company)!["bs"] as? String;

}

func profileFromJsonObject(json: NSDictionary) -> UserProfile?{

    guard let
        id = json["id"] as? Int,
        name = json["name"] as? String,
        userName = json["username"] as? String,
        email = json["email"] as? String,
        address = json["address"] as? NSDictionary,
        phone = json["phone"] as? String,
        website = json["website"] as? String,
        company = json["company"] as? NSDictionary
        else {
            return nil
    }

    let obj = UserProfile(id: id, name: name, userName: userName, email: email, address: address, phone: phone, website: website, company: company)

    return obj
}
```

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: that's work well, but how access to address or company dictionary for show this detail in detail view?

Comment: You can use like this to access the dictionary :        print("company name : \((objUser.company)!["name"])");

Comment: Yes it is perfect way to access the dictionary data, and solve my problem.